# find values of b for which the linear system has infinitely many solutions with 1 arbitrary parameter?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} b(b-1) & 0 & b & b^2 \\ 0 & 1-b^2 & b^2 & -b \\ 
0 & 0 & b(b+1) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b(2-b)\end{array}\right]$$
**Edit:Would the same conditions hold for row equivalent matrices like A?**
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} b^2-b & 0 & b & b^2 \\ 0 & 1-b^2 & b^2 & -b \\ 
0 & b^2-1 & b & b \\
b^2-b & 0 & b & 2b\end{array}\right]$$

**Question:** Determine the values of b so that the system has

(1) No solution: **b $\ne 0 $ and b $\ne 2 $**

**Consistent System** : **b = $ 0 $ or b = $ 2 $**

(2)unique solution: **b = 2**

(3) Infinity many solns, one parameter : **no values of b found**

(4) Infinitely many solns, 2 parameters: **b = $0$**

I am not sure how to find values of b for (3)? I have tried -1 and 1,but both values of b give no solutions.

Please correct me if I am wrong about the conditions for b, thank you!

Comment: If you've stated the correct system then the first step you made was decisive. The only consistent systems are when $b=0$ and $b=2$.  Once you check those two cases, clearly we can't use them to satisfy every case  (2), (3), (4).

Comment: @hardmath thanks, would the conditions for b still hold true if the matrices like A which are row equivalent in the question(see edit) ?

Comment: Yes.  The original matrix (being upper diagonal) was easier to check.